# Java pattern capture word(s)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to capture word or words from a string like this:

```
input: "aa bb"
pattern: "(.*) bb"
expected group: "aa"
```

---

```
input: "aa yy bb xx"
pattern: "(.*) bb (.*)"
expected groups: "aa yy, xx"
```

But in my attempts it always captures whole string. Where is my mistake?

```
String patternString = "(.*) bb";
Log("patternString: " + patternString);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher m = p.matcher("aa bb");

while(m.find()) {
    Log("group: " + m.group());
    //Log: group: aa bb
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get the first group not the entire match. You should use `m.group(1)` for this, instead of `m.group()` which returns the entire match.

See the [documentation of `Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for the available API. Use `Matcher#groupCount()` to get the number of groups in the last match.

Comment: Thank you so much.